# Makefile:Missing Separator

Tags: ubuntu, makefile, gnu-make

I am trying to build a new makefile but I encountered an error, the code for the same makefile is below:

```
ifeq($(ARCH),bbb)
    $(CC)=arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc
else ifeq($(ARCH),frdm)
    $(CC)=arm-none-eabi-gcc
else
    $(CC)=gcc
endif

CFLAGS=-c
CFLAG=-o

all:memory.o data.o proj_1.o main.o
    $(CC) memory.o data.o proj_1.o main.o  $(CFLAG) main

main.o: main.c
    $(CC) main.c $(CFLAGS)

memory.o: memory.c
$(CC) memory.c $(CFLAGS)

data.o:data.c
    $(CC) data.c $(CFLAGS)

proj_1.o:proj_1.c
    $(CC) proj_1.c $(CFLAGS)

clean: 
    rm -rf *o
```

The error message is

```
test.mk:1: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

Can someone point out what I am doing incorrectly?

Thanks

Comment: Note that _make_ will expand `$(CC)=arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc` before doing the assignment. `$CC` is `cc` under normal conditions, so _make_ executes `cc = arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc`, which I doubt is what you intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a space between ifeq and `(` / `'` / `"`.

Your entire makefile can be simplified to the following, make already knows how to do most of what you've written.

```
ifeq ($(ARCH),bbb)
prefix := arm-linux-gnueabi-
else ifeq ($(ARCH),frdm)
prefix := arm-none-eabi-
endif

CC := $(prefix)$(CC)

objects := memory.o data.o proj_1.o main.o

main: $(objects)
clean: ; $(RM) $(objects) main
```

Answer (score 1):

The space between `ifeq` and the `(` bracket is missing. The GNU documentation explains the syntax [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Conditional-Example.html).